# Adding single token nodes to existing datastax cassandra Cluster and data transfer is not working

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise

Adding a new single token per nodes to existing datastax cluster and data transfer is not working. Process followed is mentioned below. Please update me if the process i followed is wrong.Thanks

We have 3 Single token range datastax nodes in our AWS EC2 Datacenter, both Search and Graph enabled. We are planning to add 3 more nodes into into our datacenter. We are currently using DseSimpleSnitch and Simple network topology for our keyspace.**Also our current replication factor is 2**.

**Node 1 : 10.10.1.36

Node 2 : 10.10.1.46

Node 3 : 10.10.1.56**

```
 cat /etc/default/dse | grep -E 'GRAPH_ENABLED=|SOLR_ENABLED='
   GRAPH_ENABLED=1  
   SOLR_ENABLED=1
```

**Datacenter : SearchGraph**

```
Address     Rack          Status   State    Load      Owns Token               
10.10.1.46  rack1       Up     Normal  760.14 MiB  ? -9223372036854775808                  
10.10.1.36  rack1       Up     Normal  737.69 MiB  ? -3074457345618258603                   
10.10.1.56  rack1       Up     Normal  752.25 MiB  ? 3074457345618258602
```

**Step (1)** For adding 3 new node into our datacenter first we changed our keyspace topology and snitch to network aware.

1)Changed the snitch.
    cat /etc/dse/cassandra/cassandra.yaml | grep endpoint_snitch:
      endpoint_snitch: GossipingPropertyFileSnitch

```
cat /etc/dse/cassandra/cassandra-rackdc.properties |grep -E 'dc=|rack='
  dc=SearchGraph
  rack=rack1
```

2) 
  (a) Shut down all the nodes, then restart them.

(b) Run a sequential repair and nodetool cleanup on each node.

3)Changed keyspace topology.

```
ALTER KEYSPACE tech_app1 WITH REPLICATION = {'class' : 'NetworkTopologyStrategy', 'SearchGraph' : 2};
ALTER KEYSPACE tech_app2 WITH REPLICATION = {'class' : 'NetworkTopologyStrategy', 'SearchGraph' : 2};
ALTER KEYSPACE tech_chat WITH REPLICATION = {'class' : 'NetworkTopologyStrategy', 'SearchGraph' : 2};
```

Reference : http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/operations/opsChangeKSStrategy.html ,  http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/operations/opsSwitchSnitch.html

**Step (2)** For updating token range and setting up new cassandra node, we follow below process.

1) Recalculate token range

```
root@ip-10-10-1-36:~# token-generator
```

DC #1:

```
Node #1:  -9223372036854775808
Node #2:  -6148914691236517206
Node #3:  -3074457345618258604
Node #4:                    -2
Node #5:   3074457345618258600
Node #6:   6148914691236517202
```

2) Installed Datastax enterprise same version on new nodes.

3) Stopped the node service and and cleared the data.

4) (a) Assigned token range in following manner to new node.

```
Node 4: 10.10.2.96     Range: -2 
Node 5: 10.10.2.97     Range: 3074457345618258600
Node 6: 10.10.2.86     Range: 6148914691236517202
```

4) (b) Configured cassandra.yaml on each new node:

Node 4 :

```
cluster_name: 'SearchGraph' 
num_tokens: 1
initial_token: -2  
parameters: 
- seeds: "10.10.1.46, 10.10.1.56" 
listen_address: 10.10.2.96 
rpc_address: 10.10.2.96 
endpoint_snitch: GossipingPropertyFileSnitch
```

Node 5 :

```
cluster_name: 'SearchGraph' 
num_tokens: 1
initial_token: 3074457345618258600  
parameters: 
- seeds: "10.10.1.46, 10.10.1.56" 
listen_address: 10.10.2.97 
rpc_address: 10.10.2.97
endpoint_snitch: GossipingPropertyFileSnitch
```

Node 6 :

```
cluster_name: 'SearchGraph' 
num_tokens: 1
initial_token: 6148914691236517202   
parameters: 
- seeds: "10.10.1.46, 10.10.1.56" 
listen_address: 10.10.2.86 
rpc_address: 10.10.2.86 
endpoint_snitch: GossipingPropertyFileSnitch
```

5) Changed the snitch.

```
cat /etc/dse/cassandra/cassandra.yaml | grep endpoint_snitch:
endpoint_snitch: GossipingPropertyFileSnitch

cat /etc/dse/cassandra/cassandra-rackdc.properties |grep -E 'dc=|rack='
dc=SearchGraph
rack=rack1
```

6) Start DataStax Enterprise on each new node in two minutes intervals with consistent.rangemovement turned off:

```
JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Dcassandra.consistent.rangemovement=false
```

7) After the new nodes are fully bootstrapped, used nodetool move to assign the new initial_token for existing nodes as per token recalculation done at step 4(a). Process done on each node one at a time.

```
On  Node 1(10.10.1.36)  :  nodetool move -3074457345618258603
On  Node 2(10.10.1.46)  :  nodetool move -9223372036854775808
On  Node 3(10.10.1.56)  :  nodetool move  3074457345618258602
```

**Datacenter: SearchGraph**

```
Address     Rack        Status State   Load            Owns                Token

10.10.1.46  rack1       Up     Normal  852.93 MiB ? -9223372036854775808
10.10.1.36  rack1       Up     Moving  900.12 MiB ? -3074457345618258603
10.10.2.96  rack1       UP     Normal  465.02 KiB ? -2
10.10.2.97  rack1       Up     Normal  109.16 MiB ? 3074457345618258600
10.10.1.56  rack1       Up     Moving  594.49 MiB ? 3074457345618258602
10.10.2.86  rack1       Up     Normal  663.94 MiB ? 6148914691236517202
```

**Post Updated:**

But we are getting following error while joining nodes.

```
AbstractSolrSecondaryIndex.java:1884 - Cannot find core chat.chat_history
AbstractSolrSecondaryIndex.java:1884 - Cannot find core chat.history
AbstractSolrSecondaryIndex.java:1884 - Cannot find core search.business_units
AbstractSolrSecondaryIndex.java:1884 - Cannot find core search.feeds
AbstractSolrSecondaryIndex.java:1884 - Cannot find core search.feeds_2
AbstractSolrSecondaryIndex.java:1884 - Cannot find core search.knowledegmodule
AbstractSolrSecondaryIndex.java:1884 - Cannot find core search.userdetails
AbstractSolrSecondaryIndex.java:1884 - Cannot find core search.userdetails_2
AbstractSolrSecondaryIndex.java:1884 - Cannot find core search.vault_details
AbstractSolrSecondaryIndex.java:1884 - Cannot find core search.workgroup
AbstractSolrSecondaryIndex.java:1884 - Cannot find core cloud.feeds
AbstractSolrSecondaryIndex.java:1884 - Cannot find core cloud.knowledgemodule
AbstractSolrSecondaryIndex.java:1884 - Cannot find core cloud.organizations
AbstractSolrSecondaryIndex.java:1884 - Cannot find core cloud.userdetails
AbstractSolrSecondaryIndex.java:1884 - Cannot find core cloud.vaults
AbstractSolrSecondaryIndex.java:1884 - Cannot find core cloud.workgroup
```

Node joining failed with following error :

```
ERROR [main] 2017-08-10 04:22:08,449  DseDaemon.java:488 - Unable to start DSE server.
com.datastax.bdp.plugin.PluginManager$PluginActivationException: Unable to activate plugin com.datastax.bdp.plugin.SolrContainerPlugin


Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot find secondary index for core ekamsearch.userdetails_2, did you create it? 
If yes, please consider increasing the value of the dse.yaml option load_max_time_per_core, current value in minutes is: 10

ERROR [main] 2017-08-10 04:22:08,450  CassandraDaemon.java:705 - Exception encountered during startup
java.lang.RuntimeException: com.datastax.bdp.plugin.PluginManager$PluginActivationException: Unable to activate plugin
```

**Has anyone encountered these errors or warnings before?**

Comment: Any particular reason while you are manually assigning tokens, while you could set numtoken = 1 in Cassandra.yaml and let Cassandra handle it for you.

Comment: I had already configured num_tokens: 1 and also initial_token range as per recalculation mentioned in above Step 2 (1). We want to assign initial_token range manually, not Cassandra to handle it because i think current cluster Solr will not work if we change it and rebalanced using Opscenter, please clarify if i am wrong. Is the above steps we followed is correct ? for adding nodes.

Comment: I believe its tedious to manually manage tokens as you scale the cassandra nodes. The num_tokens:1 itself will automatically help manage that at Cassandra level and as the data gets rebalanced to the new node Solr will index them. As the data moves to the new node the corresponding records are removed from old node, as you run nodetool cleanup. As the records die in old nodes so are the corresponding index entries in Solr. From the Solr core you will be able to see the number of records being indexed and you can validate after adding the nodes. I would avoid manual distribution of tokens.

Comment: So we can start 3 new nodes with num_tokens:1 and what about existing 3 nodes in cluster which has initial_token: already set.Thanks

Comment: Easiest way is to decommission them one at a time as it moves the data to the newly joint nodes. You can add them back without initial token with replace_address

Comment: Thanks, let me try to follow the steps you have mentioned above. Also is there any other Keyspaces topology we had to change to "NetworkTopologyStrategy"  other than tech_app1,tech_app2 and tech_chat keyspace we had created for our application.

Comment: Also while changing to vnode do i need to change num_tokens: 1 too  num_tokens: 256 . Thanks

Comment: Num_tokens is the way of configuring vnodes, so set it to 1. Also on topology strategy use system_auth as well with network topology.

Comment: @dilsingi  I am getting following errors while data migration.                                                                                                                        java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot find secondary index for core search.userdetails_2, did you create it?      AbstractSolrSecondaryIndex.java:1884 - Cannot find core cloud.userdetails
AbstractSolrSecondaryIndex.java:1884 - Cannot find core cloud.vaults
AbstractSolrSecondaryIndex.java:1884 - Cannot find core cloud.workgroup

Comment: Reload the solr core without reindexing. by default I think it starts reindexing, so be careful with the command

Comment: @dilsingi I have Solr data in existing cluster, while it get transfered to new nodes i am getting "solr not found" error. Will reloading the Solr core solve the issue in new nodes while joining time , because  we have existing data in old nodes. Please check the above post , i have updated the question.

Comment: Another way out normally is to bootstrap as just data node (non-solr) and once data has been completely streamed during bootstrap, it will jump to normal. Once that happens reboot that node as search node and reload the core. While reloading the core you can also say distributed=false, which would avoid impact on any other solr nodes and reindex only this node.

Comment: @dilsingi so i need to do following step in new node 1) enable only graph in dse.yaml conf file for new nodes 2) After jump to normal, Enable solr too in dse.yaml conf file  3) Reboot the new nodes after solr is enabled 4) Reload the core in new nodes one by one with distributed=false.  Also current DC name in old node is "SearchGraph" do i need to change it in new nodes while starting as non-solr as you have mentioned

Comment: Keep the datacenter same as your old cluster.

Comment: Thanks @dilsingi Issue get solved .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Token Assign Issue ::**

```
1) I had wrongly assigned token range in Step 4) (a). Assign token which 
   bisect or trisect the value which are generated using  
   "token-generator"
         Node 4: 10.10.2.96     Range: -6148914691236517206 
         Node 5: 10.10.2.97     Range: -2
         Node 6: 10.10.2.86     Range: 6148914691236517202

Note : We don't need to change the token range of existing nodes in data   
       center.No need to follow procedure in Step 7 which i have mentioned 
       above.
```

**Solr Issue resolved : Cannot find cor ::**

```
Increased load_max_time_per_core value in  dse.yaml configuration file, 
still i was receving the error.Finalys solved the issue 
by following method

     1) Started the new nodes as non-solr and wait for all cassandra data  
        to migrate to joining nodes.
     2) Add the parameter auto_bootstrap: False directive to the 
        cassandra.yaml file
     3) Re-start the same nodes after enabling solr. Changed parameter 
        SOLR_ENABLED=1 in /etc/default/dse
     3) Re-index in all new joined nodes. I had to reloaded all core 
        required with the reindex=true and distributed=false parameters in 
        new  joined nodes. 
        Ref : http://docs.datastax.com/en/archived/datastax_enterprise/4.0/datastax_enterprise/srch/srchReldCore.html
```